# How do you access the ruler?

Tags: measurement

No matter what I select or where I look I can't find the ruler anywhere. I'm using Blender 2.74, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Open the toolbar in the 3D Viewport using <kbd>T</kbd>. Navigate to the *Grease Pencil* section and click the 'Ruler/Protractor' button. You can now click and drag in the 3D Viewport to create a ruler and or protractor measurement.

[image: Ruler GIF]

Comment: how to save this ?

Comment: @haidarvm how to save what . . ?

Comment: save the ruler so we can modiefied or render it ?

Comment: @haidarvm You can't turn it into a mesh or curve object as far as I am aware. You might be able to with some scripts

Answer (score 2):

For those landing here after Blender 2.8 release: `shift` + `spacebar` + `m`. Or:

[image]

Plus: nice video (not mine) introducing how to use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZECjQS5yVo

Comment: Thank you. I found the measure tool but wasn't able to accurately measure from point to point. Only after watching this video did I learn I was supposed to hold the ctrl button when clicking.