# Guidelines equivalent alternative in Blender?

Tags: snapping

Many 2D graphic editors have "guidelines" (Corel Draw) or "guides" (Adobe Illustrator) feature. These are temporary invisible geometry, useful for snapping.

Is there similar feature in Blender?

Or how to perform similar functionality in Blender?

May be draw helper object on separate layer or something?

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28746/how-do-you-access-the-ruler ?

Comment: This is reverse task. I found rulers, which can be used to measure already existing objects. I would like opposite: create new object under guiding of some helper objects.

Comment: I sometimes create temporary objects: cubes, edges or curves for this purpose.

Comment: You can create an edge, snap its vertices to grid (for the sake of accuracy), in *View* panel activate visualizing length of edges; then use vertex snapping while modeling your objects, so you'll snap to that edge.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274/how-to-model-effectively-using-exact-measurements